# CustomColors colors in ExtJS 4 menu color picker (Ext.menu.ColorPicker)

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, color-picker

and thank you for viewing this message!

I have a problem in one of my projects that uses a Ext.menu.ColorPicker
I don't know why (and it's probably something very simple, i hope) but the picker simply does not assume the custom colors that i need it to have!

Here is some sample code, that illustrates my problem:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
var customColors = [
        'fa7166', 'cf2424', 'a01a1a', '7e3838', 'ca7609', 'f88015', 'eda12a', 'd5b816',
        'e281ca', 'bf53a4', '9d3283', '7a0f60', '542382', '7742a9', '8763ca', 'b586e2',
        '7399f9', '4e79e6', '2951b9', '133897', '1a5173', '1a699c', '3694b7', '64b9d9',
        'a8c67b', '83ad47', '2e8f0c', '176413', '0f4c30', '386651', '3ea987', '7bc3b5'
    ];

var picker = Ext.create('Ext.picker.Color');

picker.colors[0] = '556677';
picker.colors = customColors;

    var btn = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        menu: {
            xtype: 'colormenu',
            picker: picker,
            value: 'FFFFFF',
            handler: function (obj, rgb) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('border-color: ' + rgb.toString());
            } // handler
        }, // menu
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        text: 'Menu Button'
    }).showMenu();
}); // onReady()
```

The line:

```
picker.colors[0] = '556677';
```

works perfectly, has you can see, i can change the element 0 of the array.
But this line:

```
picker.colors = customColors;
```

Should assign the whole array of new colors to the picker, i don't know why, but it doesn't seem to work.
I need the component to have all of those colors, 32 colors not the 40 default colors that are default on the picker!

How should i do this?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: customColors not costumColors

Answer (score 1):

You are you using the wrong combination of widgets, you are embedding a [`Ext.menu.ColorPicker`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.menu.ColorPicker) inside another [`Ext.menu.Menu`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.menu.Menu), instead of that you should use the `Ext.menu.ColorPicker` as is, and then you will be good to go, like this

```
var customColors = ['fa7166', 'cf2424', ...];
var pickerMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.ColorPicker');
pickerMenu.picker.colors = customColors;

var btn = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    menu: pickerMenu, // menu
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    text: 'Menu Button'
}).showMenu();
```

[Here's](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/49m) a modified version of your code that works with the custom color list. Hope it helps to solve your problem.